# How to publish a High Trust Apps for SharePoint 2013 (Provider Hosted) to a SharePoint OnLine

Tags: 2013

I have developped a High Trust App for SharePoint 2013 (Provider-Hosted) on SharePoint On-Premise.

Also, I wonder if that is possible to publish this App to a SharePoint OnLine ?

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Arioule

Answer (score 0):

High trust apps require you to install a cert on the server, which you can't do for SharePoint online, so they are for on-prem use only.

Take out the high-trust part, and yes, you can have a provider hosted app where the app is published to sharepoint online and the remote web application is hosted on your server.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your answer.

Is there any documentation describing how to create a Low trust apps (Provider-Hosted) ?

Or is there any way to turn a high trust app to a Low trust app ?

Regards,

Arioule

Comment: There are quite a few instructions for how to create low trust apps. Unfortunately, the vast majority are for hosting the remote web app in azure with the app in 0365. These instructions will still work, but just use your locally hosted app instead of azure, but follow the rest of the instructions. This should work: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steve_fox/archive/2013/02/18/building-your-first-provider-hosted-app-for-sharepoint-using-windows-azure-part-1.aspx